# Recursive Approach is not working on Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a C code template, and I need to complete it to have a binary search tree and then improve it to be an AVL tree. In the code template, there were given to me some declarations of necessary functions and the definition of struct. But I am having troubles with the BST.

Here is the struct which is given to me in the code template;

```
typedef struct NODE_s *NODE;
typedef struct NODE_s
{
    NODE right;
    NODE left;
    unsigned long long data;
    int height;
} NODE_t[1];
```

Firstly, I tried to write a node initializer function. Simply, it takes an `unsigned long long` data as parameter, and uses it to initialize a new unique node, then returns it. What I am confused here is the usage of the **name** of the struct in memory allocation part. Here is the function;

```
NODE node_init(unsigned long long data)
{

    NODE newNode = (struct NODE_s*)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE_s));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->height = 1; 
    return newNode;

}
```

Thereafter, I tried to code a **recursive insertion function** for my tree. It simply takes two parameters. I showed my thinking way on writing these codes with the comment lines to make it clear for you.

```
NODE avl_insert_recursive(NODE node, unsigned long long data){

    if( node == NULL){ // if the node is NULL, then assign the data directly to it.

        return(node_init(data)); // call the node initializer function, initialize a node with the value of data
    }

    if( data < node->data ){ // if the data is smaller than the node's data


        node->left = avl_insert_recursive(node->left, data);


    }else if( data > node->data){ // if the data is bigger than the node's data


        node->right = avl_insert_recursive(node->right, data);


    }else{ // if equality occurs, directly return the node itself.

        return node;
    }
```

Lastly, to test my tree, I have a function over there. But, for the purpose of simplifying it in my question, I am going to pick over the necessary lines;

```
 NODE node = node_init(NULL); // firstly, initializing an empty node for a recursive tree
 int i = 0;
 unsigned long long number; // The numbers will be stored in it.

 fp = fopen(fname, "r+"); // There will be a .txt consist of unsorted long numbers.

 for(i = 0; i<n; i++){

        fscanf(fp, "%llu\n", &number); // taking numbers line by line
        node = avl_insert_recursive(node,number); // inserting each number to our tree
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

So as a conclusion, I shared the necessary lines and functions above and tried to simplify it as much as I can. The problem is, this code does not work. The function named `avl_insert_recursive` is not working recursively and stucking after 2-3 loop, as I checked it with `printf` statements. So if anyone out there can spend their time to read these lines of codes and help me to solve this problem, I will be very appreciated. Thanks for help.

Comment: Removing C++ tag, because everything here smells **`C`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `return` statements from some of your paths in `avl_insert_recursive`.  This results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Where exactly should I add a return statement in avl_insert_recursive function ?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Consder:  What should `avl_insert_recursive` return after assigning to `node->left`?

Comment: It should not return anything until the recursive loop ends and it reaches a leaf. Once it reaches a leaf, then we should return the node after if statements ? Am I true ?

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Every call _has_ to return something.  What should that be in the cases where you do not have a `return` statement?

Comment: So, after `node->left`and `node->right` recursion lines, I need to return something. Should it be `node` what I need to return ?

Comment: Actually when I returned `node`, the tree started to work. Thank you so much for helping.